# Commit Transaction in Java Class Design

Tags: java, jsf

I am looking for a best strategy in Java class design.
I am using JSF 2.1 and basically I have a class which places an order and retrieves from a web service.

- I want to commit the transaction or rollback if there is an error using
  this class.

What is the best approach in-terms of class design I can take to address this.
Do I need to use nested class design?
I have at-least 15 methods that has to work in coordination to make sure that even if one fails, the transaction is rolled back.
Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: You may do it in the scope of transaction, it doesn't matter what class design you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSF is a view technology.  If you're doing things right, it shouldn't be involved in transactions at all.

JSF view should talk to a controller.  The controller should have a reference to a service, which is the object that knows about units of work and transactions.  The service orchestrates model objects, persistence objects, and other services to fulfill the use case.

The logic to acquire database connections and commit or rollback a transaction belongs in the service.

If you're using aspect-oriented programming, it's easy to do.  (That's how Spring does it.)

```
view--->controller--->service--+--->persistence
                               |
                               +--->model
```

It's called a layered design.  The dependencies ought to follow the arrows as I drew them.  Model and persistence don't know about service, controller, or view.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I am using EJB and not Spring. So what Roman C mentioned helps me. I did search other stack flow articles and I found this useful link regarding EJB. http://entjavastuff.blogspot.cz/search/label/EJB3

Comment: EJB is doing it via aspects and annotations, just like Spring.  No surprise - Rod Johnson was on the EJB3 committee.  They learned a lot from Spring.

Comment: I have to give you the correct answer credit because you did initiate the answer in the right direction. Thanks duffymo.